# Want the game to terminate after 6 trials

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to exit the game after 6 trials. However, the game is continuing even after 6 trials.

I have applied a while count_trials <=6. It should go to the else part after the count_trails exceeds 6, isn't it? However, it's going beyond 6 and showing something like:
"Great Prashant! you guessed the number right in 9 guesses"

```
from random import randint
#Asking the user a number
def ask_a_number():
    playernumber = int(input('Guess a number: '))
    return playernumber

#Comparing the numbers and giving hints to the player about the right number
def compare_2_nos(num1, num2):
    if (num1 < num2):
        if abs(num1 - num2) > 3:
            print('Your number is too low')
        else:
            print ('Your number is slightly low')
    if (num1 > num2):
        if abs(num1 - num2) > 3:
            print('Your number is too high')
        else:
            print ('Your number is slightly high')

#Running the Guess the number game
name = input('Enter your name: ')
print ('Hi {}! Guess a number between 1 and 100').format(name)
num1 = ask_a_number()
count_trials = 1
num2 = randint(1,100)
while count_trials <= 6:
    while num1 != num2:
        compare_2_nos(num1, num2)
        num1 = ask_a_number() 
        count_trials += 1
    else:
        print ("Great {}! you guessed the number right in {} guesses".format(name, count_trials))
        break
else: 
    print ("You have have exceeded the number of trials allowed for this game")
```

I am expecting the game to print "You have have exceeded the number of trials allowed for this game" after 7 or more trials

Comment: Your `while num1 != num2:` loop will continue until the number is guessed, regardless of what `count_trials` is.

Comment: A note to help you in the future -- you will benefit by working with a good IDE (eg. PyCharm) with debugging capabilities. You can step through your code line by line and generally catch your own errors that way. I've been programming a long time and wouldn't dream of coding without a debugger : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program never gets out of the inner while loop.Also, you are asking for a number before the loop starts.So, for 6 trials your check condition should be `count_trials<6`.Try this

```
while count_trials < 6:
        count_trials += 1
        compare_2_nos(num1, num2)
        num1 = ask_a_number()
        if num1 == num2:
            print ("Great {}! you guessed the number right in {} guesses".format(name, count_trials))
            break    
else:
    print ("You have have exceeded the number of trials allowed for this game")
```

Answer (score 2):

The first bug you have is on line 22, you should put `.format()` right after the string.

And you are creating a 'infinite loop' since you are not increment count_trials every loop.
just change the while loop like this

```
while count_trials <= 6:
    if num1 != num2:
        compare_2_nos(num1, num2)
        num1 = ask_a_number()
    else:
        print ("Great {}! you guessed the number right in {} guesses".format(name, count_trials))
        break
    count_trials += 1
```

or using a for loop with `range(1, 7)` as iterable.

Answer (score 1):

while loops are notorious for creating these kinds of problems.

My suggestion is to use a for loop that iterates over the exact number of trials you want, with an if condition that tests for success:

```
for trial in range(1, 7):
    if num1 == num2:
        print ("Great {}! you guessed the number right in {} guesses".format(name, trial))
        break
    compare_2_nos(num1, num2)
    num1 = ask_a_number()
else:
    print ("You have have exceeded the number of trials allowed for this game")
```

This also means you don't have to keep a 'counter' variable which you need to continue adding to, as seen with `count_trials`